# baposter problem compiling

Tags: compiling, baposter

I have this code, and I need to edit some thing on it but it cannot compile on overleaf !!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,margin=1cm,fontscale=1]{baposter} % echelle de la police (initial Ã  0.285)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5mm} % espace entre les colonnes Ã  l'intÃ©rieur des cadres
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % largeur du filet entre les colonnes
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand{\Syst}[2]{\left\{\begin{array}{l} #1\\ #2 \end{array}\right.}
\setitemize{label=\ding{71},leftmargin=5mm,itemsep=0mm,parsep=0mm,topsep=0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\newcommand{\mili}[4]{\psgrid[subgriddiv=10, gridlabels=0, gridwidth=0.4pt, subgridwidth=0.4pt,gridcolor=brown!80,subgridcolor=brown!40](#1,#2)(#3,#4)}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1cm}}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb Z}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\C{{\mathbb C}}
\def\e{{\text{e}}}
\newcommand{\V}{\overrightarrow} % Vecteurs
\newcommand{\Repc}{(O;\V{u};\V{v})} % RepÃ¨re Ouv
\newcommand{\Coor}[2]{\begin{pmatrix} #1\\#2 \end{pmatrix}} % CoordonnÃ©es
\newcommand{\Ree}{\mathfrak{Re}} % partie rÃ©elle
\newcommand{\Ima}{\mathfrak{Im}} % partie imaginaire
\newcommand{\Abs}[1]{\left \lvert#1\right \rvert} % module

\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\begin{document}


\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=open, % Ajout d'une bordure autour de l'entÃªte des boites 
background=none, 
%bgColorOne=green, % Couleur de fond pour le dÃ©gradÃ© sur le cÃ´tÃ© gauche de l'affiche
%bgColorTwo=yellow, % Couleur de fond pour le dÃ©gradÃ© sur le cÃ´tÃ© droit de l'affiche
colspacing=6mm, % Espace entre les boites
columns=6,
borderColor=black, % Couleur des bordures de cadres
headerColorOne=darkgray, % Couleur de fond pour l'en-tÃªte dans les boites (cÃ´tÃ© gauche)
headerColorTwo=green, % Couleur de fond pour l'en-tÃªte dans les boites (cÃ´tÃ© droit)
headerFontColor=white, % Couleur du texte de l'en-tÃªte des boites
boxColorOne=gray!10, % Couleur de fond des boites
textborder=roundedleft, % Format des bordures : none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright, faded
eyecatcher=true, % false pour supprimer le logo de gauche
headerheight=0.075\textheight, % Hauteur de l'en-tÃªte
headershape=roundedright, % Format des bordures de l'entÃªte : rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\textsc\bf,% Police de l'en-tÃªte : large, bold et sans serif %\textsc, 
textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{0em}}, % Indentation
linewidth=1pt % Largeur du filet des boites boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EN-TÃŠTE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
{\mbox{}\hspace*{0.5cm}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Complexe.eps}} %gauche
{\mbox{}{\Huge Nombres complexes}}{\footnotesize Terminale S} %titre
{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Logo_Nath.eps}\hspace*{0.5cm}\mbox{}}%droite
% 

%---------------------
% Fiche
%---------------------

\headerbox{\bf Forme trigonomÃ©trique} %%%%%%%
{name=tri,column=2,span=2}
{
\center{\large $z =\Abs{z}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Module : \\
   $\Abs{z}=\sqrt{z\ \overline{z}}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
   \item Argument : \\
   $\arg(z) =\theta=(\V{u},\V{OM}) [\;2\pi]$ \\
   $\cos \theta = \dfrac{a}{\Abs{z}}$ \; ; \; $\sin \theta =\dfrac{b}{\Abs{z}}$
\end{itemize}
}

\headerbox{\bf Forme algÃ©brique} %%%%%%%
{name=alg,column=0,span=2,bottomaligned=tri}
{
\center{\large $z=a+ib$}
\begin{itemize}
   \item $i^2 =-1$
   \item $a =\Ree(z) \to$ partie rÃ©elle \\
   $b =\Ima(z) \to$ partie imaginaire
   \item ConjuguÃ© : $\overline{z}=a-ib$
   \item $\C$ = \{nombres complexes\}
\end{itemize}
\bigskip
}

\headerbox{\bf Forme exponentielle} %%%%%%%
{name=exp,column=4,span=2,bottomaligned=tri}
{
\center{\large $z =r\,\e^{i\theta}$}
\begin{itemize}
   \item $r =\Abs{z}>0$
   \item $\theta =\arg(z)$
   \item $\e^{i\theta} =\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$
   \item $\e^{-i\theta} =\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$
\end{itemize}
}

\headerbox{\bf ReprÃ©sentation graphique} %%%%%%%
{name=rep,column=0,span=6,below=tri}
{
{\psset{unit=1.2}
\begin{pspicture}(-7.5,-2.7)(7.5,2.9)
   \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none,linecolor=darkgray]{->}(0,0)(-5,-2.5)(5,2.5)
   \psline{-|}(0,0)(1,0)
   \psline{-|}(0,0)(0,1)
   \psline[linewidth=0.05,arrowsize=10pt]{->}(0,0)(3,2)
   \psline{<-}(-3,-2)(0,0)
   \psline{<->}(3,-2)(-3,2)
   \rput(-0.1,-0.2){\footnotesize $0$}
   \rput(1,-0.2){\footnotesize $1$}
   \rput(0.6,-0.2){\footnotesize $\V{u}$}
   \rput(-0.2,1){\footnotesize $i$}
   \rput(5.8,0){\small\it\darkgray partie rÃ©elle}
   \rput(0,2.7){\small\it\darkgray partie imaginaire}  
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](-3,-2)(-3,2)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](3,-2)(3,2) 
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](-3,-2)(3,-2)  
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](-3,2)(3,2) 
   \rput(3.7,-0.15){\red $a=r\cos \theta$}
   \rput(0.7,2.2){\blue $b=r\sin \theta$}
   \rput(-3,-0.2){\red $-a$}
   \rput(-0.01,-2.2){\blue $-b$}
   \rput(3.4,2.15){\small $M(z)$}
   \rput(3.45,-2.15){$M_1(\overline{z})$}
   \rput(-3.6,-2.15){$M_2(-z)$}
   \rput(-3.6,2.15){$M_3(-\overline{z})$}
   \rput{32}(1.2,1.1){$r =\Abs{z} =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$}     
   \rput(1.7,0.3){$\theta =\arg(z)$} 
   \psarc[linewidth=0.05]{->}(0,0){1}{0}{35}
\end{pspicture}}
}

\headerbox{\bf PropriÃ©tÃ©s du conjuguÃ©} %%%%%%%
{name=pal,column=0,span=2,below=rep}
{
\begin{itemize}
   \item $\overline{z+z'}=\overline{z}+\overline{z'}$
   \item $\overline{z \times z'}=\overline{z}\ \times \overline{z'}$ \smallskip
   \item $\overline{\left(\dfrac{z}{z'}\right)}=\dfrac{\overline{z}}{\overline{z}'}$ \medskip
   \item $\overline{z^n} =(\overline{z})^n$
   \item $z\in\R \iff z=\overline{z}$
   \item $z\in i\,\R \iff z=-\overline{z}$
   \item $z =0 \iff \Ree(z) =\Ima(z) =0$ \smallskip
\end{itemize}
}

\headerbox{\bf PropriÃ©tÃ©s du module/argument} %%%%%%%
{name=pma,column=2,span=2,below=rep,bottomaligned=pal}
{
\begin{itemize}
   \item  $\Abs{-z}=\Abs{\overline{z}}=\Abs{z}$
   \item $\Abs{zz'} =\Abs{z}\Abs{z'}$
   \item $\arg(zz')=\arg(z)+\arg(z') \,[2\pi]$
   \item $\Abs{z^n} =\Abs{z}^n$
   \item $\arg(z^n)=n\arg(z) \,[2\pi]$
   \item $\Abs{\dfrac{z}{z'}} =\dfrac{\Abs{z}}{\Abs{z'}}$
   \item $\arg \left(\dfrac{z}{z'}\right)=\arg(z)-\arg(z')\,[2\pi]$
\end{itemize}
}

\headerbox{\bf PropriÃ©tÃ© de l'exponentielle} %%%%%%%
{name=exp,column=4,span=2,below=rep,bottomaligned=pal}
{
\begin{itemize}
   \item $r\e^{i\theta}\times r\e^{i\theta'} =rr'\e^{i(\theta+\theta')}$
   \item $\left(r\e^{i\theta}\right)^n =r^n\e^{i n\theta}$ \smallskip
   \item $\dfrac{1}{r\e^{i\theta}} =\dfrac{1}{r}\e^{-i\theta}$\smallskip
   \item $\dfrac{r\e^{i\theta}}{r'\e^{i\theta'}} =\dfrac{r}{r'}\e^{i(\theta-\theta')}$\medskip
   \item $\overline{r\e^{i\theta}} =r\e^{-i\theta}$
\end{itemize}
}

\headerbox{\bf Lien complexes-gÃ©omÃ©trie} %%%%%%%
{name=lcg,column=0,span=3,below=pal,above=bottom}
{
\begin{itemize}
   \item $z_{\V{AB}} =z_B-z_A$ \quad et \quad $AB =\Abs{z_B-z_A}$ \smallskip
   \item $\Abs{z-z_A} =r$ : cercle de centre $A$ de rayon $r$ \smallskip
   \item $\Abs{z-z_A} =\Abs{z-z_B}$ : mÃ©diatrice de $[AB]$ \smallskip
   \item $(\V{u},\V{AB}) =\arg(z_B-z_A)$ \smallskip
   \item $\arg(z-z_A) =\theta\,[2\pi]$ : {\small demi-droite d'origine $A$ d'angle $\theta$} \smallskip
   \item $(\V{AB},\V{CD}) =\arg\left(\dfrac{z_D-z_C}{z_B-z_A}\right)$
   \item $\V{AB}$ et $\V{CD}$ orthogonaux $\iff \dfrac{z_D-z_C}{z_B-z_A}\in i\R$ \smallskip
   \item $\V{AB}$ et $\V{CD}$ colinÃ©aires $\iff \dfrac{z_D-z_C}{z_B-z_A}\in\R$
\end{itemize}
}

\headerbox{\bf Lien complexes-trigonomÃ©trie} %%%%%%%
{name=lct,column=3,span=3,below=pal}
{
Formule de Moivre : $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n =\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$ \\
Formules d'Euler : $\cos\theta =\dfrac{\e^{i\theta}+\e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ ; $\sin\theta =\dfrac{\e^{i\theta}-\e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$
}

\headerbox{\bf Lien complexes-second degrÃ©} %%%%%%%
{name=lcd,column=3,span=3,below=lct,above=bottom}
{
$az^2+bz+c =0$, $\Delta =b^2-4ac$
\begin{itemize}
   \item $\Delta >0$ : 2 racines rÃ©elles $\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$
   \item $\Delta =0$ : 1 racine double $\dfrac{-b}{2a}$
   \item $\Delta <0 $: 2 racines conjuguÃ©es $\dfrac{-b\pm i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}$
\end{itemize}
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example is hardly mininmal. over 200 lines, and we can not run it as we do not have the input images, however the file has been corrupted by double encoding as UTF-8, see `\headerbox{\bf Lien complexes-second degrÃ©} %%%%%%%`  the accented A is a sign that a UTF-8 file has been interpreted as iso-8859-1 (latin1) and then re-encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Unrelated, but note that `\bf` has not been  defined by default in latex for almost 30 years.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Officially `\bf` is not defined, but in reality it is defined in article.cls.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum yes sure but contributed classes like this one could drop it at any time, as users of the koma-script classes found when they dropped this1980s compatibility command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure. I think it would be better if it gave a warning.

Comment: I tried your file on Overleaf with the correct encoding and it works.